# How to make a autosuggest using these json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

I was trying to load JSON data from a 3rd party API link where I can pass keywords as a city name.
like Keywords=newyork and based on that keyword it gives me a list of city or area data like below:

```
{
"account":null,
"accountId":0,
"accountType":0,
"accountProfile":0,
"unreadMessages":0,
"database":"dbname",
"entity":"geo",
"method":"wSearchCity",
"result":1,
"message":null,
"data":[
  {
    "id": "145086",
    "name": "New York City, NY"
  },
  {
    "id": "99600",
    "name": "Newport News, VA"
  },
  {
    "id": "139934",
    "name": "Newark, NJ"
  },
  {
    "id": "39964",
    "name": "New Orleans, LA"
  },
  {
    "id": "108279",
    "name": "New Haven, CT"
  },
  {
    "id": "13073",
    "name": "Newark, DE"
  },
  {
    "id": "139922",
    "name": "New Brunswick, NJ"
  },
  {
    "id": "119774",
    "name": "New Bedford, MA"
  },
  {
    "id": "63726",
    "name": "New Bern, NC"
  },
  {
    "id": "108261",
    "name": "New Britain, CT"
  }
]
}
```

Now What I wanted to make an input field which will give me runtime names from this JSON data on typing city name.

I have tried many methods that are available on google and stackoverflow but nothing helps.
Please give me some Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json={"account":null,"accountId":0,"accountType":0,"accountProfile":0,"unreadMessages":0,"database":"dbname","entity":"geo","method":"wSearchCity","result":1,"message":null,"data":[{"id": "145086","name": "New York City, NY"},{"id": "99600","name":"Newport News, VA"},{"id": "139934","name": "Newark, NJ"},{"id": "39964","name": "New Orleans, LA"},{"id": "108279","name": "New Haven, CT"},{"id": "13073","name": "Newark, DE"},{"id": "139922","name": "New Brunswick, NJ"},{"id": "119774","name": "New Bedford, MA"},{"id": "63726","name": "New Bern, NC"},{"id": "108261","name": "New Britain, CT"}]};

$("input[type='text']").on("keyup",function(){
  var Val=$(this).val();
  $("span").empty();
  $(json.data).each(function(key,value){
    if ((value.name).search(Val) != -1) 
     $("span").append(value.name + " | "+value.id).append("<br>");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<br>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. But if I type 'N' it's giving me value and autosuggest me but if I type New the autosuggest become empty.

Comment: you are welcome. But I tested it and worked like a picture correctly. https://ibb.co/byYRgR

Comment: For me, it's not working like the screenshot you sent. Not sure why. Same from my localhost and same from the code snippet.

Comment: please check in other browser

Comment: Wait a bit to test other methods

Comment: i change code by other method. pleass use `keyup` dont use `keydown`